# how to use simple "IF" statement on textblock

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Hi I have a little problem.

I'm using data binding to retrieve data from an internet source..
All goes wel and the data is perfectly presented in a textblock that resides within an data template.

So far so good..

I'm trieng to use the if statement on that textblock

like:

```
    if (textblock.Text == ("good")

    {Do some stuff here}
```

I've added an Loaded event handler to the textblock and now I'm able to do:

```
    private void loadedevent_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        if (1 == 1)
        {
            textBlock2.Text = textBlock.Text;
        }
    }
```

I did that just to see if the text gets copied over to textBlock2. (So I know that works)

and here comes the problem:

When I say:

```
    private void loadedevent_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        if (textBlock.Text == "good")
        {
            do some stuff here
        }
    }
```

It just wont trigger and I'm 1000% sure that the text inside the textblok == "good"

Please help been.. fighting with this for over 2 days...

Comment: Any trailing newline characters? Essentially, how did you make sure that the text really says “good”?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the `if` condition to see what `textBlock.Text` *really* is? I wouldn't be surprised to hear it's just a matter of some leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Congrats; you got a Jon Skeet comment! :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph" how did you make sure that the text really says “good”?"    Because thats what is printed on the screen and also the xml link shows me that it says "good" and also when I do the following: Textblock.Text = Textblock1.Text I get the same copy of the textbox.

Comment: @youngblade I’m asking *you* that question, since it clearly isn’t …

Comment: @JonSkeet How do I put a breakpoint on the if statement.. I'm ready to do anything to resolvethis issue..

Comment: @youngblade: You put the cursor on that line and press F9, then start debugging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using textblock.Text.Trim().Equals("good")

Also as someone else has said, Loaded is probably called before the data gets loaded. Try using the Shown event or the Textbox change event.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanx for your reply.. but Loaded isnt called before the data gets loaded becaus I'm using an 4 seconds timer.. but I'm going ahead and try your sugestion.. :-)

Comment: Yess..!!!! Finaly...!!!! It seems that there is more than meets the eye inside the textblock.. textblock.Text.Trim().Equals("good") did the job...!!! may I guess that it trimmed the textbox down..??  Please explain it a little bit more.. :-)

Comment: Trim() removes all whitespace and newline characters that are not visible when simply looking at the Textbox. BTW, why are you using a timer? generally you do not want to have your users waiting on data and I assume these calls are already synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

> It just wont trigger and I'm 1000% sure that the text inside the textblok == "good"

I am not similarly convinced.  You are essentially claiming that the language is broken.  I can guarantee you that it is not.

`Text` != `"good"`, that much is obvious.  Make sure you don't have unprintable characters in there (newline(s) and leading/trailing whitespace are obvious ones to check).

I see no mention of you using a debugger at all.  This should be your goto tool for stuff like this.  Have you checked the value at runtime in the debugger?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010.. I hit F5 and the debugger does its work.. I also tried: Text != "good" and it seems you are right.. textblock.Text == "good" is not true.. but thats what it shows in the emulator.. maybe there are some extra values present that arent visible

Answer (score 1):

The Loaded event is probably firing before the Text of the TextBlock is set.

Comment: I don't see how using a timer would make a difference. Paste the entire snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to use

```
 SourceUpdated  Occurs when the source value changes for any existing property binding on this element. (Inherited from FrameworkElement.)
```

This event will allow you to see if the entered value == good (real time)

edit: In the code behind, you just check the value of your text block. (remember, you must declare the event on your TextBlock in the xaml)